# what would be the best practice for http request in webapi project with softdelete

Tags: httprequest, asp.net-core-webapi, soft-delete

I am working on a webapi .Net5 project. I am using SQLserver and EF5 to store my entities. Each of my entities has a property called `IsDeleted`, which I use for remove(`IsDeleted=true`) and restore(`IsDeleted=false`).

I am a bit confused which http request method should I use for my remove/restore endpoints.

1. I am updating a partial part of my entity (`isdeleted`), so I was thinking about `PATCH`
2. I also don't want to show the client that I am doing soft delete, then for remove, I was thinking about `DELETE` but I really do not delete any entity from my resources
3. I was also thinking about `PUT`, but in both cases, I do not have any request body and therefore it is very rare that a `PUT` method has not have any body .
4. I saw in some StackOverflow question and answers that they recommend to use a `POST` method for restore and `DELETE` for remove when using the soft delete but did not really understand why.

Anybody knows what would be the correct way of doing that and why?

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTP `DELETE` to update `IsDeleted` = `true` is up to you as the API designer. There's no law saying HTTP `DELETE` must hard-delete whatever it refers to.

If the client does not know you're soft-deleting the record it'd be entirely appropriate to use `DELETE`.

I work with a system which has soft-delete, but it is not hidden from the client app / user. So to soft-delete it is either a `PUT` request to `api/some_endpoint/24601` with `"status": "ARCHIVED"` within the payload, or a `POST` request to `api/some_endpoint/24601/actions` with a similar payload. (`PATCH` may be more appropriate than `PUT` but the API designers have stuck with `PUT` throughout.)

Comment: thanks jack. therefore , we have always one endpoint for remove/restore but with different payload , right ?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it, to let the client/user soft-delete and restore!

Comment: what i am doing now is have two endpoints :  1- PUT api/remove/{id}   2- PUT  api/restore/{id}   both endpoints has no request payload . for soft-delete and restore , i need to do some logics like check if a property has an existing dependent entity and for restore needs to check lots of logics before restore an entity is there a problem with what scenario i am doing now or shall i modify this to the PUT method with a body of status as you already mentioned ( if i good understand , use a payload with property of status , Archived for remove and restore for restored ) .   many thanks